# Query Caching MySQL

Tags: mysql, caching

I try to work with Query Caching. The cache should stores the query together with the result. So i enabled the Query Cache in my.cnf.
On the duration shows me that it works:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
SELECT * FROM t_data GROUP BY col2;  //duration: 0.034sec
SELECT * FROM t_data GROUP BY col2;  //duration: 0.015sec
SELECT * FROM t_data GROUP BY col2;  //duration: 0.014sec
```

Actually everything is fine but after that I used EXPLAIN on this query.
Thats the result:

```
id |  select_type | table  | type  |  possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref | rows  | Extra

1  |  SIMPLE      | t_data | ALL   |                 |      |         |     | 921   | Usi..
```

So why i get 921 in column rows? The Result has only 15 rows. If thought that MySQL take the table which is connected by this query in the cache. Why searched MySQL again the whole table?
Is my first post. I hope everything is correct!

Comment: Your table is tiny. I wouldn't use those speed gains (tiny as well) as proof that query cache is enabled. Instead, verify that `HAVE_QUERY_CACHE` is `YES`, `QUERY_CACHE_SIZE` is greater than zero and `QUERY_CACHE_TYPE` IS `1`. Said that, cached queries do not run again —that's the point— and they shouldn't affect execution plan at all.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't InnoDB store the row count?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/why-doesnt-innodb-store-the-row-count)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thank you for your answer. All this varaibles hat correct values in my.cnf. I tried the same with an bigger table (also only 13000 rows). And if i disable the query cache i will get the whole time same duration. I´m sure that the cache is enabeld. So my question is why search mysql the whole table instead only the stored table for this query?

Comment: The values in `my.cnf` are probably the actual ones but, again, when in doubt it's always better to see the current runtime values directly, as in ``show variables like '%CACHE%'``. I'm still not sure though about the exact question you're asking. When you run `explain ...` you get [quoting the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) "a query execution plan (that is, an explanation of how MySQL would execute a query)". But a cached query does not need to be executed!

Comment: Great, your last two sentences was the answer on my question^^. Thank you a lot for your time and help

Comment: Really? Alright, I've composed a proper answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [execution plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) is *an explanation of how MySQL **would execute** a query* (emphasis mine). In other words, it's the result of asking MySQL how it would handle a given SQL query to fetch the requested information. As such, it's normally a good estimation on how fast the query will be, but it doesn't imply an actually query execution. Also, it doesn't show actual row numbers either, mainly because it normally won't know the real figure and it'd be impossible to get it without actually running the query.

On the other side, the [MySQL Query Cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) is a feature to avoid query execution altogether:

> The query cache stores the text of a SELECT statement together with
>   the corresponding result that was sent to the client. If an identical
>   statement is received later, the server **retrieves the results from the
>   query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again**.

The metrics you would obtain upon an actual query execution are called [profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profile.html); it's an entirely different thing. Some DBMSs offer pretty good per-query profiling features, MySQL as far as I know only has some generic data.